# Install windows 11 on a physical disk thrught virtualbox, to use later as normal windows 11 boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, virtualbox, ssd, virtual-machine

i will soon update my build from more than 10 years old.

is possible to use virtualbox or any other VM software to format a real/physical disk and install windows 11 for later use this disk in the new machine? is that possible? how?

i see some tutorials as how use physical disks in virtualbox but none of then makes clear if that disk will be a 'normal' disk afterwards, that can be used on a 'normal' PC to use as OS boot disk

to be more specific i pretend do that on a pcie ssd, and in theory when the new machine comes i just plug the sdd(after execute the generalization/sysprep  of win11) on the new machine and boot normally.

any information about this is useful!

Comment: If your host has UEFI, GPT disk, Secure Boot, and TPM V2, you should be able to install Windows 11 as a VM and then V to P it when ready. VMware Workstation offers both P2V and V2P for this kind of work.

Comment: VMWare Workstation has the ability to support a virtual TPM and UEFI. The host machine doesn't necessarily need to support it. This comment just extends John's comment.